# Re-use of same Activity, reloading ContentView

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, xamarin

I have an activity that's used for multiple purposes. When I go to this activity from the `Main Activity`, the `Second Activity` starts, and loads its `ContentView`. When I go back I'm back at the `Main Activity`. But when I go to the `Second Activity` again I have to press the back button twice to get back to the `Main Activity`, and when I go to the `Second Activity` again, I have to press the back button three times.... and so on...

So I guess this is due to the `SetContentView()` being called, while the `contentview` never got destroyed.

Of course I tried to do this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.DetailView);
    // Populating depending on Intent.GetStringExtra()
}

protected override void OnPause() {
    base.OnPause();
    Finish();
}
```

I also tried `OnStop()`, but this just finished the activity, not the `contentview` I guess?

Or am I looking in the wrong direction?

Comment: I don't think `Finish()` is needed in `OnPause()` at all, use `Finish()` when you have a button that takes you back to the previous activity

Comment: You're right, but I thought that it would kill the entire activity, but I was wrong... I'm just looking for something that kills the entire activity so that I can make a completely new instance...

Comment: when you go back to the `MainActivity`, how do you do that, with `StartActivityForResult()`?

Comment: I don't use that method... I just go back, and from there just: Inten activity = new Intent(this, typeof(DetailView)); activity.PutExtra("string", "value"); StartActivity(activity);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overlooked the fact that I was starting the second activity in the OnResume() instead of the OnCreate()

So the previous delegation was still present, while it created a new one when I pressed a grid button... Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

If you press back twice to get back to the MainActivity it means that the SecondActivity was still active and not finished correctly.

Have a look at the Android Activity [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: So that's why I thouht calling fninish() like I showed in my snippet would end the life cycle of the activity...

Comment: Try to use the onBackPressed function and finish the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Android maintains a stack of activities, everytime you use `StartActivity()` the activity is pushed on the stack.

When you press the "back" on the phone, the last activity is popped from the stack.

Therefore, if you want to programmatically return to the previous acitivity, then you have to call `Finish()` instead of `StartActivity()`.

Comment: This I know, so how do I take the activity away from the stack? Calling Finish() in the OnPause()/OnStop() doesn't do that...

Comment: you shouldn't call `Finish()` in those methods, do you use a button to go back to the previous screen?

Comment: No, not a custom button, just the Android button since users wil automatically use that...

Comment: that should work then, maybe you accidentally push activities on the stack. I would find out how to print out the stack and then see what's on there